# How select distinct from composite primary key table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to understand how to filter out a `select` from a SQL table with two primary keys like this:

```
╔═══════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ First Primary Key ║ Second Primary Key ║ Data       ║
╠═══════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1                 ║ 1                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 1                 ║ 2                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 1                 ║ 3                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 1                 ║ 4                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 2                 ║ 5                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 2                 ║ 6                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 2                 ║ 7                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 3                 ║ 8                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 4                 ║ 9                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 4                 ║ 10                 ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 4                 ║ 11                 ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 4                 ║ 12                 ║ Bla,bla,bla║
╚═══════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

I want to `distinct` the first column and take just the `max(Second_Primary_Key)` from the second column.

What I want as result is

```
╔═══════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ First_Primary_Key ║ Second_Primary_Key ║ Data       ║
╠═══════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1                 ║ 4                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 2                 ║ 7                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 3                 ║ 8                  ║ Bla,bla,bla║
║ 4                 ║ 12                 ║ Bla,bla,bla║
╚═══════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

The structure should be like:

```
select * from foo  
where (distinct First_Primary_Key) and max(Second_Primary_Key)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select First_PK, max(Second_PK) from foo group by First_PK
```

To get the data as well I would prefer to use a window function:

```
; with temp as (
 select row_number() over (partition by First_PK order by Second_PK desc)
   as row_num, First_PK, Second_PK, data
 from test)
 select * from temp
 where row_num = 1
```

Comment: I like the window function but how to have the maximum value from 'where row_num = 1' instead of 1 i need 'max'

Comment: Are you sure? The `desc` keyword is there for this reason, so that the  max `Second_PK` per `First_PK` comes first (hence row_num = 1). Is it something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a `group by` and then `join` with it like

```
select t1.first_primary_key, xxx.second_primary_key, t1.data
from tbl1 t1 join (
select first_primary_key, max(second_primary_key) as second_primary_key
from tbl1 
group by first_primary_key ) xxx 
on t1.first_primary_key = xxx.first_primary_key
AND t1.second_primary_key = xxx.second_primary_key;
```

Comment: I think you are missing an `AND t1.second_primary_key = xxx.second_primary_key`, otherwise you return all rows.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis, Ahh ... nice catch. Thanks.

Comment: Collaboration at its best, wouldn't you say? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `row_number()` to get the highest `Second_Primary_Key` per `First_Primary_Key` (top 1 per group), using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select sub.First_Primary_Key, sub.Second_Primary_Key, sub.[Data]
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by First_Primary_Key 
        order by Second_Primary_Key desc
      )
  from t
  ) as sub
where sub.rn = 1
```

---

**`cross` [`apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** version:

```
select distinct
    t.First_Primary_Key
  , x.Second_Primary_Key
  , x.[Data]
from t
  cross apply (
    select top 1
          *
      from t as i
      where i.First_Primary_Key = t.First_Primary_Key
      order by i.Second_Primary_Key desc
    ) as x;
```

---

**[`top with ties`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) version:

```
select top 1 with ties
    *
  from t
  order by 
    row_number() over (
      partition by First_Primary_Key
      order by Second_Primary_Key desc
      )
```

---

This `inner join` version has the same issue as using `rank()` instead of `row_number()` in that you can get multiple results for the same First_Primary_Key if a First_Primary_Key has more than one row with the same max Second_Primary_Key.

`inner join` version:

```
select t.*
from t
  inner join (
    select MaxSecond_Primary_Key = max(Second_Primary_Key), First_Primary_Key
    from t
    group by First_Primary_Key
    ) as m
      on t.First_Primary_Key  = m.First_Primary_Key
     and t.Second_Primary_Key = m.MaxSecond_Primary_Key;
```

Comment: That's a long and nice answer