# How select * from composite primary key table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I learned [How select distinct from composite primary key table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773051/how-select-distinct-from-composite-primary-key-table) :

```
; with temp as (
 select row_number() over (partition by First_PK order by Second_PK desc)
   as row_num, First_PK, Second_PK, data
 from test)
 select * from temp
 where row_num = 1
```

but I now face another problem, instead of `where row_num = 1` I would like to have `where row_num = MAX` (I mean the maximum value)

[How select distinct from composite primary key table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773051/how-select-distinct-from-composite-primary-key-table)

Comment: Can you specify your sample data and expected output..?

Comment: I want to `SELECT *` depending  by the maximum value of `Second_PK`

Comment: Because you are ordering Second_PK in *descending* order, selecting `where row_num = 1` should *already* give you the maximum value for Second_PK (based on your partition by First_PK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was:

```
; with temp as (
 select row_number() over (partition by First_PK order by Second_PK)
   as row_num, First_PK, Second_PK, data
 from test)
 select * from temp
 WHERE row_num=(SELECT max(row_num) FROM temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

As last row in one sort order will be the first row in the opposite sort order, you can just change the `order by` clause to use ascending order in the window function `row_number`:

```
; with temp as (
 select row_number() over (partition by First_PK order by Second_PK)
   as row_num, First_PK, Second_PK, data
 from test)
 select * from temp
 where row_num = 1
```